# I don't know how to use the then operator of Project Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I don't know how to use the then operator of Project Reactor. I don't quite understand the javadoc of this operator. Who can explain this to me? With some code examples would be great. I myself wrote an example like below:

```
public class Test11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3);
        Mono<Void> mono1 = flux.then();
        mono1.subscribe(null, null, () -> System.out.println("yes1"));
        flux.subscribe(System.out::println, System.err::println);
    }
}
```

I thought the result would be:

```
1

2

3

yes1
```

But the actual result is:

```
yes1

1

2

3
```

Please help me. And I hope you can write some code examples and no restriction to this example I wrote here.

Comment: As a slight nitpick, `.then()` is a method of the `Flux` object, not an operator.

Comment: we can call it an operator.@bluevulture

Comment: 1. No you can't. A method is not a keyword. Don't misuse standard terminology. 2. There is no [tag:operator-keyword] here. This is Java, not C++. Don't tag indiscrimately.

Comment: OK. I won't call it operator. Can you tell me how to use it? @user207421

Comment: @user207421 This is a bit of a corner case in that, since we're dealing with reactive Java, `then()` is in fact a *reactive operator* that's implemented as a *method* on `Flux`. So it's certainly not incorrect to call it an operator, but clearly it's nothing to do with C++ operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`then()` is used when you don't care about what elements a publisher has output, you only care about when it finishes. So it takes an existing publisher, throws all of its elements away, and then propagates the completion signal.

However, I'm not sure your misunderstanding here comes from the `then()` operator itself, but instead the behaviour of reactive publishers upon subscription (and possibly that all reactive chains are immutable.) Of relevance here:

- Nothing happens until you subscribe;
- You can subscribe multiple times, and the entire chain will execute again every time you subscribe.
- Whenever you use an operator on a chain, a new copy of that reactive chain is created with the new operator appended - you don't mutate the existing chain.

So in this case, line by line:

- We have a `flux` chain which will emit 3 elements immediately upon subscription (1,2,3)
- We have a `mono1` chain which will emit nothing and complete immediately (since it's created from the above `flux`, so has nothing to wait for)
- We subscribe to the `mono1` chain with a subscriber that does nothing aside from print `yes1` when it completes - and as per the above, it completes immediately and prints `yes1`
- We subscribe to the original flux with a subscriber that prints each element as it's emitted, hence it prints 1, 2 & 3.

If you just want a notification (yes1) to be printed when the publisher completes, then you could just scrap the `mono1` entirely, doing:

```
flux.subscribe(System.out::println, System.err::println, () -> System.out.println("yes1"));
```

...which would give you the output you expect.

The `then()` operator can really serve no use here, since it will always complete immediately. As above. you would only really use it in the case where you have to wait for something to complete, and you don't care about whatever it might emit in the meantime - say, for example, you have a flux of database updates you want to execute and you only care when they're all done, or you're making a PUT request you don't need a result from, you just need to know when it's complete.